# In App Purchase in Flutter not Fetchhing Past Purchases in Different Device

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

Hey guys I am currently working on a project with in app purchase I can fetch past purchases if I use the device that purchased a product but if I change device with the same Apple ID there are no records of past purchases. I already used [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) and [flutter_in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inapp_purchase) both of their functions in fetching past purchases' have the same result

Comment: I assume your app isn't available on the App Store and therefore you tested only in the sandbox?

Comment: My App is on the App Store but the testing is only in sandbox, we tried it testing it in another device and got no receipt, is it normal if we are just using the testing account?

Comment: Yes, this is "correct" behavior for sandbox. Trigger a `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` and also your second device should get the (correct) receipt

Comment: SKReceiptRefreshRequest will work as pastPurchase in in_app_purchase right? thanks bro

Comment: It will fetch the latest receipt and therefore you will have access to all previous purchases